# Where can I get a power adapter for a Visioneer 4400 USB scanner?

Tags: spare-parts

My parents have a reasonably ancient Visioneer 4400 USB scanner. The power supply has died. (I figured this out because I have a hard drive enclosure with a very similar power supply, and it worked.)

Where can I find a replacement one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one on eBay, by searching for the model number on the back of the plug (ys-1015-k12s):

http://shop.ebay.co.uk/?_from=R40&_trksid=m38&_nkw=ys-1015-k12s

Comment: Always a good spot to start when looking for hardware.

Comment: The start of the 1st sentence read like the ad. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it felt a bit odd writing it. I’d Googled a bit, and I found a similar question on another (much inferior) Q&A site. I answered it there, but I figured if I put the info on Super User as well, there’d be more chance of other people finding it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The eBay thing didn’t actually work out — the item got lost in the post, and the chap was out of stock after that.

I found one at Blackmore though: http://blackmoreit.com/products/parts-power-supplies-ac-adapters/ys-1015-k12-ya-hsin-ys-1015-k12-12vdc-1.25a-uk-plug-ac-adapter.html

I’ve ordered it; I’ll update here if/when it turns up.